# Is there a toString function LibreOffice calc?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have a data in one cell that's formatted like `1999/02/20`.
I want to use the concanate function to turn it into `+1999/02/20T00/00/00`. Is there a toString function that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the TEXT function, the following should convert the number 1999/02/20 which is in cell A1 for example to the string 1999/02/20:

```
TEXT(A1, "yyyy/mm/dd")
```